# Run Length Encoding in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List

data Encoding = Multiple Int Char | Single Char deriving (Eq,Show,Ord)
```

Encoding of run length

```
encode :: String -> [Encoding]
encode inputString =encoding (group inputString) []


encoding :: [String] -> [Encoding] -> [Encoding]
encoding groupString xs=
if (length groupString == 0)
    then xs
else
    case (head groupString) of
            ([c]) ->encoding (tail groupString)  (xs ++ [Single c])
            (x) -> encoding (tail groupString)  (xs ++ [Multiple (length x) (head x)])
```

Decoding of run length

```
decode :: [Encoding] -> String
decode listString = decoding listString []              

decoding :: [Encoding] -> String -> String
decoding inputString xs=
if (length inputString == 0)
    then xs
else
    case (head inputString) of
        (Single x) ->decoding (tail inputString) (xs++ [x])
        (Multiple num x) ->decoding (tail inputString) (xs ++ (replicate num x) )
```

This is my run length encoding solution, can anyone suggest me a better way to write encoding and decoding functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of your code is dedicated to updated an accumulator. You add elements to the tail of that accumulator, and this will have a drastic impact on performance.

The reason this is usually not very efficient is because a list in Haskell `[a]` is implemented - at least conceptually - as a *linked list*. As a result concatenating two lists `l1` and `l2` together with `l1 ++ l2`, will take *O(|l1|)* time (that is the number of elements in `l1`). So that means that if the list already contains 100 elements, adding one extra at the end will require a lot of work.

Another anti-pattern is the use of `head` and `tail`. Yes these functions can be used, but unfortunately since you do not use pattern matching, it could happen that an empty list is passed, and then `head` and `tail` will error.

Another problem here is that you use `length` on a list. Since sometimes lists in Haskell can have infinite length, the `length` call will - if we need it - never ends.

In cases where you have to append at the end of the accumulator, usually we can write the recursion in the tail of a list "cons" we are building. So we can rewrite our program from:

```
encode :: String -> [Encoding]
encode [] = []
encode (h:t)  = ...
```

The question is now how we can count these values. We can use [**`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span), a function that will - for a given predicate and a list - construct a 2-tuple where the first item contains the prefix of the list where all elements satisfy the predicate, and the second item contains the rest of the list, so we can use this like:

```
encode :: String -> [Encoding]
encode [] = []
encode (h:t)  | nh > 1 = Multiple nh h : tl
              | otherwise = Single h : tl
    where (s1, s2) = span (h ==) t
          nh = 1 + length s1
          tl = encode s2
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> encode "Foobaaar   qqquuux"
[Single 'F',Multiple 2 'o',Single 'b',Multiple 3 'a',Single 'r',Multiple 3 ' ',Multiple 3 'q',Multiple 3 'u',Single 'x']
```

For the decoding, we again do not need an accumulator, and can make use of [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate):

```
decode :: [Encoding] -> String
decode [] = []
decode (Single h:t) = h : decode t
decode (Multiple nh h) = replicate nh h ++ decode t
```

Or we can use a list monad instead:

```
decode :: [Encoding] -> String
decode = (>>= f)
    where f (Single h) = [h]
          f (Multiple nh h) = replicate nh h
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> decode [Single 'F',Multiple 2 'o',Single 'b',Multiple 3 'a',Single 'r',Multiple 3 ' ',Multiple 3 'q',Multiple 3 'u',Single 'x']
"Foobaaar   qqquuux"
```

Comment: You know this, but another way to add items to the end of a list is to add each new element to the beginning of a strict accumulator, then reverse the list to get it in the proper order. This is faster than appending, because when you add to the end of an immutable list, the previous last node needs to be replaced with one that links to the new last node, then the node before that needs to be replaced with one that links to the new second-to-last, and so on, until you’ve copied the entire list with each insertion and your algorithm now takes quadratic time.

Comment: @Davislor: yeah, I know we can use a "reverse accumulator", but I am not convinced that this is much faster at all, since reversing takes time as well, and furthermore it can create a huge load on memory (since it is not said we want the entire encoding anyway).

Comment: Not saying that it is or isn’t a better approach to this problem. Mainly I remember trying to figure out why my `accum ++ [x]` function was so slow, and I figure someone else at the same stage, like the OP, would benefit from the explanation.

Comment: @Davislor: fair point, I updated the answer and explained why appending to the right is usually not a good idea :).

Answer (score 3):

As an extension to [Willem Van Onsem's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670039/3058609), consider creating the run lengths separately, then combining them together with their letters with `zipWith`.

`Data.List` has the function [`group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) (which itself is a specialization of the generic `groupBy`; `group = groupby (==)`) which breaks strings into homogenous substrings. i.e.:

```
group "aaabbccccd"
= ["aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d"]
```

Calculating the length of each will give you run-length.

N.B. that `group` is implemented exactly the same way as Willem's `span` solution.

```
import Data.List (group)

data Encoding = Multiple Int Char
              | Single       Char
  deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

encode :: String -> [Encoding]
encode xs = zipWith op lengths letters
  where
  groups  = group xs
  lengths = map length groups
  letters = map head   groups

  op :: Int -> Char -> Encoding
  op 1 = Single
  op n = Multiple n
```

This could also be done as one very ugly list comprehension.

```
encode xs = [ let (n, c) = (length g, head g)
              in  if   n == 1
                  then Single c
                  else Multiple n c
            | g <- group xs ]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `encoding` function is a functional map.  Instead of making your own primitive recursive function just use `map`.
2. Your encoding is reversing the output (`xs ++ [Single c]` etc) which is both counter intuitive and computationally expensive.  Stop it.
3. Too many parenthesis, such as on `case (..) of`, `if (...) then` and the arms of the case `(...) ->`.  All these are unneeded and clutter the code.
4. If you type `head` chances are you should have pattern matched somewhere instead.

Consider:

```
encoding :: String -> [Encoding]
encoding = map enc . group       -- Point 1, use map which also takes
                                 -- care of point 2 and 3.
 where
 enc [x]      = Single x
 enc xs@(x:_) = Multiple (length xs) x -- Point 4, patterns not `head`
 -- Here consider make pattern matches total either via an error call or Maybe type
```