# Count elements on ordered list

Tags: list, haskell

I want to do a Haskell function where the input (a list of Strings) is ordered (always. input is valid only if is ordered) and I want to get the number of occurrences of each different string.

Example:

```
ContaOcs["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d"]
```

Should return:

```
[(2,"a"), (1,"b"), (3,"c"), (1,"d")]
```

Here is What I'm trying to do:

```
module Main where

contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
contaOcs [] = [_,_]
contaOcs [x] = [1,x]
contaOcs (i, x1:x2:xs)
 | x1 == x2 =  (i+1,(x2:xs))
 | otherwise = (0, (x2:xs))
```

But this code have some errors and I'm not so sure how I should do to accomplish this
I'm new to functional programing and Haskell. Can anyone help me with some information?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably a duplicate. Anyway the linked question mentions (in the question itself) an answer to this question. [How to group similar items in a list using Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12398458/791604)

Comment: near dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669774/run-length-encoding-in-haskell

Comment: EDIT: Thanks everyone for the help. More then 1 answer solves the problem. I up-voted all good answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some syntactical problems as well as problems with the types. The first line looks like:

```
contaOcs [] = [_,_]
```

But an underscore (`_`) in the result does not makes any sense, you can only construct lists with values in it. When we count the number of occurences of an empty list, the result will be an empty list, so `contaOcs [] = []`.

As for the second:

```
   contaOcs [x] = [1,x]
```

Here you aim to return a list with two elements: a `1` and an `x` (which is a `String`). In Haskell the elements of a list all have the *same* type. What you can do is return a list of 2-tuples with the first item an `Int`, and the second a `String`, like the signature suggests, but then you need to wrap the values in a 2-tuple, like `contaOcs [x] = [(1,x)]`.

In your last clause, you write:

```
contaOcs (i, x1:x2:xs) = ...
```

which does not make much sense: the input type is a list (here of `String`s), not a 2-tuple with an `Int`, and a list of strings.

So the input will look like:

```
contaOcs (x1:x2:xs) = ...
```

The output, like `(i+1,(x2:xs))` also is not in "harmony" with the proposed output type in the signature, this looks like a 2-tuple with an `Int`, and a list of `String`s, so `(Int, [String])`, not `[(Int, String)]`.

Based on the above comments, we have derived something like:

```
contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
contaOcs [] = []
contaOcs [x] = [(1,x)]
contaOcs (x1:x2:xs)
     | x1 == x2 =  -- ...
     | otherwise = -- ...
```

So now there are two parts to fill in. In case `x1` and `x2` are *not* equal, that means that we can first yield a tuple `(1, x1)` in the list, followed by the result of `contaOcs` on the rest of the list (`x2` included), so:

```
(1, x1) : contaOcs (x2:xs)
```

In the latter case, it means that we first make a recursive call to `contaOcs` with `(x2:xs)`, and then *increment* the counter of the first item of that list. We are sure such element exists, since we make a recursive call with a list containing *at least* one element, and by induction, that means the result contains at least one element as well, since the base case contains one element, and the recursive case either prepends elements to the result, or updates these.

So we can use a pattern guard, and maniplate the result, like:

```
contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
contaOcs [] = []
contaOcs [x] = [(1,x)]
contaOcs (x1:x2:xs)
     | x1 == x2, ((yi, yv):ys) <- contaOcs (x2:xs) = (yi+1, yv) : ys
     | otherwise = (1, x1) : contaOcs (x2:xs)
```

We can also use an "*as-pattern*": we only need a reference to the tail of the list starting with `x2`, not `xs`:

```
contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
contaOcs [] = []
contaOcs [x] = [(1,x)]
contaOcs (x1:xs@(x2:_))
     | x1 == x2, ((yi, yv):ys) <- contaOcs xs = (yi+1, yv) : ys
     | otherwise = (1, x1) : contaOcs xs
```

The above is however not very elegantly. It might be better to use an *accumulator* here, I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is the most complete one.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at some of the errors mentioned by ghc. Always pay close attention to when GHC talks about Expected and Actual types, as these messages are always illuminating. `Expected` indicates what GHC *thinks* you should write.  `Actual` indicates what you wrote. You either need to change what you wrote (read: change your code), or change what GHC thinks you should write (read: change your type annotations). In this case it's mostly the former.

```
hw.hs:2:16: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: (Int, String)
    • In the expression: _
      In the expression: [_, _]
      In an equation for ‘contaOcs’: contaOcs [] = [_, _]
    • Relevant bindings include
        contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)] (bound at hw.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | contaOcs [] = [_,_]
  |                ^

hw.hs:2:18: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: (Int, String)
    • In the expression: _
      In the expression: [_, _]
      In an equation for ‘contaOcs’: contaOcs [] = [_, _]
    • Relevant bindings include
        contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)] (bound at hw.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | contaOcs [] = [_,_]
  |                  ^
```

The underscore is used as a placeholder (or "hole"), to be filled in later. GHC is telling you that you should figure out something to put in these holes.

```
hw.hs:3:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘(Int, String)’
      Expected type: (Int, String)
        Actual type: String
    • In the expression: x
      In the expression: [1, x]
      In an equation for ‘contaOcs’: contaOcs [x] = [1, x]
  |
3 | contaOcs [x] = [1,x]
  |
```

You have declared that the return type of the function is `[(Int, String)]`, in other words, a List, where each element of the list is a Tuple of `Int` and `String`.

Therefore, each element in the list should be a Tuple. The syntax `[1,x]` means a list with two elements: `1` and `x`. GHC has noticed that `x`, however, is known to be a `String`, which is not a Tuple. (GHC failed to notice that 1 is not a tuple, for... reasons. Numbers in Haskell are a little weird and GHC is not so helpful with those.)

Perhaps you meant to write `(1, x)`, which is a tuple of 1 (an `Int`) and x (a `String`). However, don't forget to *also* put that tuple into a list somehow, since your return type is a *list* of tuples.

```
hw.hs:4:10: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[String]’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer, [a0])’
    • In the pattern: (i, x1 : x2 : xs)
      In an equation for ‘contaOcs’:
          contaOcs (i, x1 : x2 : xs)
            | x1 == x2 = (i + 1, (x2 : xs))
            | otherwise = (0, (x2 : xs))
  |
4 | contaOcs (i, x1:x2:xs)
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

GHC is again reminding you that it expects a list of tuples, but in this case, you gave it just one tuple.

The errors are mostly the same as this.

Answer (score 4):

```
contaOcs ::  [String] -> [(Int, String)]
```

`contaOcs` consumes a list of strings: `xss`, for each unique string: `xs` in `xss`, we produce a pair: `p`, whose first element represents the number of occurrences of `xs` in `xss`, and the second element of `p` is that `xs` itself.

We know we need to group strings by their uniqueness and count each unique string's total occurrences. You can follow this idea and implement the rest yourself. `contaOcs` takes a list and produces a new list so list comprehension should give you what you want. You're transforming one list to another, so fmap a function that accumulates should work. You can also just use natural recursion or accumulator. Here is one way to write `contaOcs`:

```
contaOcs = (return . liftA2 (,) length head =<<) . group
```

Write down the signature, purpose statement, some sample data and test cases first, then it's just a matter of finding the solutions that best fit your need.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be done by a one-liner

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> ls = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d"]
Prelude Data.List> [(length x, head x) | x <- group ls]
[(2,"a"),(1,"b"),(3,"c"),(1,"d")]
```

I mix list comprehension with the `group` function. Basic concepts you can make yourselves familiar with.

Comment: Should be `(length x, head x)` from the OP's description, and you should add some explanation (or at the very least, pointers to docs on list comprehensions and the group function) (downvote's not mine, with small improvements this can be a good answer).

Comment: this *was* a good answer even in its first version. the swapping of the tuple is not important, and even good to cause the OP to pay attention. (-2) for *that*?? I don't understand this. ---- BTW another way of writing it is `map (length &&& head) . group`, which *is* all there is to it.

Comment: @Will Ness is always very good at beautifully cutting right into the moral of the story. My take would be the applicative way. Here is another one. `(,) <$> length <*> head <$> group`.

Comment: @Redu almost. :) but first: for me, `.` is immediately clear, but with `<$>` I need to think it over to understand which instance it is... and here too you might have thought it's `map` (I did, at first, before I checked the type), but it's actually `.`. your code is equivalent to `liftA2 (,) length head . group :: Eq b => [b] -> [(Int, b)]` but we need `map (liftA2 (,) length head) . group :: Eq b => [b] -> [(Int, b)]`. writing it as `(liftA2 (,) length head <$>) <$> group` would only be an extreme obfuscation, IMO. :)

Comment: @Will Ness Well if you think `group` as an applicative functor it should all be clear (at least not an extreme obfuscation). So `(,) <$> length <*> head` is applied to the contained value (result) of the `group` function. At the end of the day the Functor instance for `(->) r` defines `fmap` to be function composition (`.`). I said i would be taking the applicative way :)

Comment: @Redu I had a typo there, which thwarted the whole point of my remark. your code's type is `Eq b => [b] -> (Int, [b])` (I copied the wrong thing from the GHCi window). It calculates an entirely different result.

Comment: @Will Ness Yes i've got your point. It should be like `((,) <$> length <*> head <$>) <$> group` due to the nested functures. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of when a co-recursive function is helpful.

```
contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
```

We'll define `contaOcs` as the outer function that takes the list of strings and returns the tuples. First let's look at the trivial cases:

```
contaOcs [] = []
contaOcs [x] = [(1,x)]
```

Pass an empty list, and you should get back an empty list. Pass a single element list, and you should get back a list with one element: `(1, x)`. Now we can guarantee that any other list is 2+ elements long.

```
contaOcs (x:xs) = go x xs
```

`go`? What is `go` you might ask? Well let's define it in the `where` clause:

```
  where
  go cur xs = let (this, rest) = span (==x) xs
              in (succ . length $ this, cur) : contaOcs diff
```

That's kind of a lot, so let's unpack. `go` is an idiomatic term for a function helper (this could as easily be named `f` or `frobnicator`, it doesn't matter). It takes the character we're counting, which is split separately from the rest of its list, and calls it `x`. It runs a `span (==x)` against the rest of the list, which splits it into a tuple `(longestPrefixThatMatches, rest)`. We return the length of that longest prefix (plus one, since we've stripped off the front character) paired with the character itself in a tuple, then cons that with the recursive case -- handing the rest of the list back to the outer function to handle.

Answer (score 1):

```
contaOcs :: [String] -> [(Int, String)]
contaOcs xs = foldr foldContaOcs [] xs
              where foldContaOcs s [] = (1, s):[]
                    foldContaOcs s ((n, ch):xs) = if ch == s then (n + 1, s) : xs 
                                                  else (1, s): (n, ch): xs
```

Comment: removed the [x] case

Comment: does `take 2 . contaOcs $ ["a","b"] ++ repeat "c"` work? :)